# Sorl-Thumbnail : Clear cache of only one image?

Tags: python, django, sorl-thumbnail

Is it possible to clear cache of only one image from a folder. I need to use this command line : *python manage.py thumbnail clear_delete_all* but on one image and not on all images. Is it possible to give it an image path or name? Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

According to [the documentation](https://sorl-thumbnail.readthedocs.io/en/latest/management.html), that management command does not allow you to specify a filename to clean. I also do not see another alternative management command to do that work. You will likely have to clean it up manually through raw Python (though you'll have to know the filename to target).

Comment: Mmh I see... Thanks anyway for your answer ! I thought well it was'nt possible.